# Component does not allow to save the object as it reset to old value?

Tags: visualforce-component

The page shows the fields of the SObject with their expected values. I can modify these values on the page but when I press the Save button the SObject saved doesn't have any of the changes and I don't understand the reason of that.

**VF Page**

```
<apex:page> 
     <c:AccountConsoleComp parentId="{!.selectedIdFromSet}" /> 
</apex:page>
```

**Component**

```
<apex:component controller="ConsoleAccountController " allowDML="true"> 
     <apex:attribute name="objectName" type="String" required="true" description="Id of the object to be translated" assignTo="{!recordId}"/> 

     <apex:form id="form"> ...
     <apex:repeat value="{!accFields}" var="a">
          <apex:inputField value="{!acc[a]}"/> 
     </apex:repeat> 
     </apex:pageBlock> 
     </apex:form>
</apex:component>
```

**Controller**

```
public class ConsoleAccountController { 
     public Account acc{set;get;} ........ '

     public void save() { 
          Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint(); 
          try { 
               system.debug('=====Account==='+acc); 
               upsert acc; 
          } ....... 
      } 
}
```

Comment: Unless you post the relevant code you are unlikely to get an answer.

Comment: Here is the page,
<apex:page>
     <c:AccountConsoleComp parentId="{!.selectedIdFromSet}" /> 
</apex:page>

Comment: Here is the component,
<apex:component controller="ConsoleAccountController " allowDML="true">
<apex:attribute name="objectName" type="String" required="true" description="Id of the object to be translated" assignTo="{!recordId}"/>
<apex:form id="form">
....
            <apex:repeat value="{!accFields}" var="a">
                <apex:inputField value="{!acc[a]}"/>
            </apex:repeat>
    </apex:pageBlock>
</apex:form>
</apex:component>

Comment: Finally here is the controller,
public class ConsoleAccountController
{
    public Account acc{set;get;}
........
public void save() 
    {
        Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
        try
        {            
                system.debug('=====Account==='+acc);
                upsert acc; 
         }
.......
}

Comment: I have added and formatted the code to the question.  You might want to make sure you have all the necessary pieces in it to ensure it compiles.  As is, I don't think this compiles, so its tough to try to look into any issues.

Comment: Thanks for format the code, I pasted the difficult snippet where I faced the issue only, do let me know if you need more.

Comment: If you have confirmed the save method is being called (via your debug output) also confirm that it completes without any errors (e.g. does it jump into the catch branch of the try/catch).

Comment: Yes, save block runs without any issue and respective record time stamp (last modified date) is also updated.